# Deleting object in nested array in an immutable way

Tags: javascript

So this is how my data looks:

```
categories = [
  {
    name: ""
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        ...
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        ...
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: ""
    products: [
      {
        id: 3,
        ...
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        ...
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to remove a product with id 1 and this is my code:

```
categories.map(category => category.products.filter(product => product.id !== 1))
```

Is this the right code? If so how I create a new array and set it with the new values?

Comment: have you tried it?  does it work?  if not, what specific error message do you receive?

Comment: Looks good. Should work but as @DanO mentioned, you need to try it first.

Comment: @VPaul - No, it's replacing `category` objects with (filtered) `products` arrays.

Comment: @DanO that is what I am struggling with. I didnt know how to create a new array with the new values but fortunately T.J Crowder helped out. Thanks anyway

Comment: My bad, you're returning products from the filter function and then passing to the map. I guess the answer below handles that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close, but your code is replacing category objects with just their filtered `products` array, losing the rest of the object properties. You need to copy each `category` object as well as its `products` array, which you typically do via spread notation:

```
updatedCategories = categories.map(category => ({
    ...category,
    products: category.products.filter(product => product.id !== 1)
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just a modified version on T.J. Crowder's response.

The `filterGroupedBy` function is more versatile and de-coupled from the business logic.

I even created a [lodash mixin](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mixin) that you can call via:

- `_.filterGroupedBy(list, key, fn)` or
- `_.chain(list).filterGroupedBy(key, fn).value()`

### Demo

```js
const disp = (value) => console.log(JSON.stringify(value))

const filterGroupedBy = (list, key, fn) => 
  list.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      [key] : item[key].filter(entry => fn(entry))
  }))
  
_.mixin({
  'filterGroupedBy' : (list, key, fn) => filterGroupedBy(list, key, fn)
})

let categories = [{
  name: "",
  products: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]
}, {
  name: "",
  products: [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]
}]

// plain js
disp(filterGroupedBy(categories, 'products', (prod) => prod.id !== 1))

// lodash - static and chain
disp(_.filterGroupedBy(categories, 'products', (prod) => prod.id !== 1))
disp(_.chain(categories).filterGroupedBy('products', (prod) => prod.id !== 1).value())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Nested Data

If you have nested data, you can iterate through a path to target the object you want to filter on.

You just need a function similar to [`Object.byPath`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61104191/1762224) (a custom polyfill).

```js
const main = () => {
  let categories = [{
    name: "",
    products: {
      data : [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]
    }
  }, {
    name: "",
    products: {
      data : [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]
    }
  }]

  // plain js
  disp(filterGroupedBy(categories, 'products.data', p => p.id !== 1))
  
  // lodash - static and chain
  disp(_.filterGroupedBy(categories, 'products.data', p => p.id !== 1))
  disp(_.chain(categories).filterGroupedBy('products.data', p => p.id !== 1).value())
}

// Required by filterGroupedBy
if (Object.byPath === undefined) {
  Object.byPath = (obj, path) => path
    .replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1')
    .replace(/^\./, '')
    .split(/\./g)
    .reduce((ref, key) => key in ref ? ref[key] : ref, obj)
}

/* #ifndef filterGroupedBy */
const filterGroupedBy = (list, path, fn) => 
  list.map(item => {
      let lastIndex = path.lastIndexOf('.'),
          target = path.substring(0, lastIndex),
          key = path.substring(lastIndex + 1)
      return Object.assign({}, Object.byPath(item, target), {
        [key] : Object.byPath(item, path).filter(entry => fn(entry))
      })
  })

_.mixin({
  'filterGroupedBy' : (list, key, fn) => filterGroupedBy(list, key, fn)
})
/* #endif */

const disp = (value) => console.log(JSON.stringify(value))
main()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, I even went the extra step to wrap it in a lodash mixin.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added a dynamic path resolution example. This can get hairy pretty fast though...